# Error HttpResponseException: Internal Server Error

Tags: android

I m connect to my local server throgh HttpPost class
But getting the

"HttpResponseException: Internal Server Error"

Comment: You will need to post some code.

Answer (score 1):

The error means that you have problems on your server. Look at server logs for details.

Comment: but the server is getting nothing